# Flutter Image Widget: How to convert the Image widget to Byte array

Tags: image, google-maps, flutter, icons, marker

I am trying to use a network image as marker icon in google maps api. The google maps Marker accepts only the BitmapDescriptor as icon, so how do I convert my network image as icon?

BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes constructor accepts the bytes, how do I get the bytes from the Image widget?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything from here?

https://coletiv.com/blog/use-network-images-as-marker-icons-flutter-google-maps/